# Does Taiwanese Mandarin have the neutral tone?

Tags: mandarin, pronunciation, taiwan

So I'm trying to learn Taiwanese Mandarin, and apparently they don't really use the neutral tone, but if that's the case how do you say things like 子,了, and 的?

Comment: Taiwanese Mandarin basically are same with Mandarin, basically.

Comment: They use neutral tone, just much less often. And it's just an accent of Mandarin, just like so many Mandarin accents used all over the world

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are talking about 輕聲.

臺灣注音符號的聲調除了一聲、二聲、三聲、四聲以外，還有個「輕聲」.

In addition to the first, second, third, and fourth tones, there is a 輕聲 (light tone) in Taiwan.
It is also known as the fifth tone or the neutral tone.

符號是一個小圓點；直寫時，標在上方；橫寫時，標在左側。

The mark is a small dot.
When the text is written vertically, it is marked at the top.
In a horizontal print, it is marked on the left.

For [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bopomofo),

[image]

You can search 注音符號發音教學 on the YouTube site.

Answer (score 2):

I think there must be some confusion here.

Neutral tones definitely exist in Taiwanese Mandarin.

There's even a paper [here](http://www.ling.hawaii.edu/graduate/Dissertations/KarenHuangFinal.pdf) called *A Study of Neutral-Tone Syllables in Taiwan Mandarin* in which the contours of the neutral *-le*, *-de* and *-zi* are discussed in depth.